Is there any way getting proxy url from an installed shop
When you set up a form using an app proxy in Shopify, you need to tell the form where to send the data (the action URL). For example:
import { redirect } from "@remix-run/node";
import { authenticate } from "~/shopify.server";

export async function loader({ request }) {
  const { liquid } = await authenticate.public.appProxy(request);

  return liquid(
    <form method="post" action="/apps/proxy/my-action">
      <input type="text" name="field" />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}


But here’s the issue merchants can change the path where your app proxy lives.If they do that, the form’s action URL will break because it’s pointing to the old path.
I'm expecting if we can get the proxy url from an installed shop
